# Workflow createTask: How to customize regular InfoPath task template?

Tags: workflow, custom-form, form, task-list, infopath

Can I customize the InfoPath task form which is used by the regular createTask activity?

I know I can create my own form and reference that in the `elements.xml` file, but I like using `myForm.TaskProperties.Title = "Please upd...";` or is that also possible with a custom form (having `TaskProperties`)?

Basically I don't like the standard task form which gets created when using the createTask activity, so I e.g. want to delete the field "Predecessor" and delete some other fields. All I want is a task with some comment field and a "finish task" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: Create your own task form and call it via `CreateTaskWithContentType`.

A nice explanation can be found here: [CreateTask method - how to create a task based on a Custom content Type](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/93679b02-bfa9-43c2-94ad-ec45191cd478) and a tutorial on how to create your own Task form inheriting form the workflow task content type: [Wrangling SharePoint Workflows with Visual Studio](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/34032/1763)